# Put Data on text boxes Edit/Update Modal Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, bootstrap-modal, crud

So I'm doing this crud thing using modal and I think I was able to do it except that the datas from the table were not displayed at the modal's textboxes. I am able to update my table, it's just that I want the selected row's data to be displayed in the modal.

so here's how it looks:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCyZ7.png)

here's my view : the table part (view/crud/crud.blade.php)

```
        <div>
            <table class="table" id="dataTable">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">id</th>
                    <th scope="col">First</th>
                    <th scope="col">Last</th>
                    <th scope="col">Course</th>
                    <th scope="col">Action</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach ($cruds as $crud)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$crud->id}}</td>
                            <td>{{$crud->firstName}}</td>
                            <td>{{$crud->lastName}}</td>
                            <td>{{$crud->course}}</td>

                            <td>
                              <a href="#" class= "btn btn-warning edit_btn"> Edit </a>                         
                              
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
              </table>
        </div> 
    @else
      <p> No Post found </p>
        
    @endif
```

here's my view : the modal part (view/crud/crud.blade.php)

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">EDIT DATA</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        
        <form action="/crud" method="POST" id = "editForm">
              {{csrf_field()}}
              {{method_field('PUT')}}

          <div class="modal-body">              
              <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="crud_id">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" id="firstName">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" id="lastName">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Course</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="course" id="course">
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class = "modal-footer">
             {{Form::submit('Update', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

here's my js (public/js/modal.js)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable();

    //display Edit Modal
    $('.edit_btn').on('click', function(){
        

        $tr = $(this).closest('tr');

        var data = $tr.children("td").map(function(){
            return $(this).text();
           }).get();

            console.log(data);

            $('#firstName').val(data[1]);
            $('#lastName').val(data[2]);
            $('#course').val(data[3]);
        
            $('#editForm').attr('action', '/crud/' + data[0]);
            $('#editModal').modal('show');
    })
    
});
```

here's my controller: the update part

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
        $this->validate($request, [
            'firstName' =>'required',
            'lastName' => 'required',
            'course' => 'required'
        ]); 

        //Adding Data
        $crud = Crud::find($id); 
        $crud->firstName = $request->input('firstName');
        $crud->lastName = $request->input('lastName');
        $crud->course = $request->input('course');
        
        $crud->save();

        return redirect('/crud');
    }
```

and here's my route

```
Route::resource('crud', 'CrudController');
```

here's what shows in the console:

```
(5) ["9", "abcde", "abcde", "abcde", "↵                               Edit              …             Delete ↵                            "]
0: "9"
1: "abcde"
2: "abcde"
3: "abcde"
4: "↵                               Edit                          ↵                               Delete ↵                            "
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: Can you post the output of **console.log(data)**?

Comment: here's what shows in the console:

`
(5) ["9", "abcde", "abcde", "abcde", "↵                               Edit              …             Delete ↵                            "]
0: "9"
1: "abcde"
2: "abcde"
3: "abcde"
4: "↵                               Edit                          ↵                               Delete ↵                            "
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
`

Comment: why are you redirecting **return redirect('/crud');** in controller? This code makes the modal close and you want to show it, right?

Comment: I think that does not affect the modal and I updated the question with a picture to explain the problem. Pls check...thank you

Comment: @account2020 What do you think when modal popup and go to retrieve data by specific id?

Comment: Hey @account2020 , we have been helping and you never gave feedback. If my answer is correct please vote it and post how you solve it so others can have a solution in case they face the same challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable();

    //display Edit Modal
    $('.edit_btn').on('click', function(){
        
        var id = $(this).parent().prev().prev().prev().prev().text();
        var firstName = $(this).parent().prev().prev().prev().text();
        var lastName = $(this).parent().prev().prev().text();
        var course = $(this).parent().prev().text();
        
            $('#firstName').val(firstName);
            $('#lastName').val(lastName);
            $('#course').val(course);
        
            $('#editForm').attr('action', '/crud/' + id);
            $('#editModal').modal('show');
    })
    
});
```

It's probably that you will need to reset modal form when you close it and you click again on other record. If it's a bootstrap modal, you can reset it when it's closed with this example:

```
// Clears modal form when is closed
        $('#kt_modal_org').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
        $(this).find('#org-form')[0].reset();
        });
```